# NPM Run Build does not display my JSON data from the map function

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-run

I created a ReactJS app using create-react-app and it works great when running from NPM START with the address of localhost:3000, but after I use npm run build and run index.html from the Build folder, the JSON never loads from the map function. Is there a step I am missing?

All help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run build` only generates the build files at build folder , to run the project in production mode you need to upload the build folder files to a hosting provider or use some kind of local server to serve them .

There is a vscode extension which can run production files locally see the extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) .

Comment: Thanks but I did upload the Build folder to my web server. No luck. I guess I did not mention that before, but the entire Build folder is sitting on my web host now and it will will not load.

Comment: @BruceChamoff Please accept answer If it helped you in anyway .